# Is there a way to get current txqueue utilization on e.g. eth0 or tun device?

Tags: linux, networking, buffer

I have detected drops on my `tun0` interface.

They seem to have been caused by low `txqueuelen` setting. Now as I increased the `txqueuelen` value for the network device and there are no more drops yet - I am wondering is there any way to get actual current usage of network device buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking with [tc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html):

```
# tc -s qdisc show dev tun0
qdisc mq 0: root 
 Sent 889257959003266 bytes 478800964 pkt (dropped 162977296, overlimits 0 requeues 1784154649) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 1784154649
```

The important part is `backlog 0b 0p` which tells you how filled the TX queue is in packets and bytes.

Tc gets this information from kernel using [netlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) interface.

Answer (score 2):

For TCP Buffer,you can use

```
       netstat -nt
```

and look for second and third column for receive and send buffer(Recv-Q,Send-Q)

For UDP

```
       netstat -nua
```

Same way you can look inside /proc/net/{tcp,udp} and look for tx_queue & rx_queue

Same way you can use

```
          ethtool -S <nic card name>  (driver need to support)


                NIC statistics:
                rx_packets: 445
                tx_packets: 48
                rx_bytes: 56015
                tx_bytes: 5938
                rx_broadcast: 336
                tx_broadcast: 2
                rx_multicast: 89
                tx_multicast: 28
                rx_errors: 0
                tx_errors: 0
                tx_dropped: 0
```

Also just want to add there is one network parameter "tcp_moderate_rcvbuf" which is enabled by default,performs receive buffer auto-tuning.As per kernel-doc

```
     If set, TCP performs receive buffer auto-tuning, attempting to
     automatically size the buffer (no greater than tcp_rmem[2]) to
     match the size required by the path for full throughput
```

Comment: As far as I understand, `netstat` shows the _socket_ buffer aka `SO_RSVBUF`/`SO_SNDBUF` which are controled by `tcp_mem`/`udp_mem` etc. I am talking about device-specific buffer that operates with skb and controls starvation when network hardware needs data (in my case it is `tun` driver which serves as virtual nic